# realpath API returns error 22(Invalid arg) or 38(function not implemented) on latest Ubuntu 21.04 & other latest linux flavours

Tags: gnu, coreutils

```
sachin@sachin:~$ cat 1.c
#include <limits.h> /* PATH_MAX */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
void main(void) {
    char *buf=NULL; 
    
    char *res = realpath("./new-CDM/dummy.c", buf);
    
    printf("result = %s",res);
    printf("\nerrno = %d\n",errno);
    printf("\nBuf = %s\n",buf);
}
sachin@sachin:~$ gcc 1.c
sachin@sachin:~$ ./a.out 
result = /home/sachin/new-CDM/dummy.c
errno = 22

Buf = (null)
```

The same program when it ran on Ubuntu 18.04 or 20.04 gives no error.

Answer (score 0):

From `man 3 realpath`:

> If there is no error, realpath() returns a pointer to the resolved_path.

From `man 3 errno`:

> The value in errno is significant only when the return value of the call indicated an error (i.e., -1  from  most  system calls;  -1 or NULL from most library functions); a function that succeeds is allowed to change errno.

Therefore there is no error, and the value of `errno` is officially *undefined*.

---

The actual value returned is an internal detail which was implemented differently in the past.  Currently (21.10), the `errno` is left over from `realpath` internally trying to follow symbolic links on path components which aren't, just in case.

You can see this best by making `dummy.c` be a symbolic link to a file `target.c`, and then running `strace ./a.out` to trace linux kernel calls, specifically the lines:

```
readlink("/home/sachin/new-CDM", 0x7ffee6b57960, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/home/sachin/new-CDM/dummy.c", "target.c", 1023) = 8
readlink("/home/sachin/new-CDM/target.c", 0x7ffee6b57960, 1023) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
```

The calls to `readlink` with non-symbolic path components failed, and changed `errno` to "EINVAL (Invalid argument)".

In the past (20.04), `readlink` was only called after an additional check the component was a link with `lstat`, therefore preserving the value of `errno`.

```
lstat("/home/sachin/new-CDM", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0775, st_size=20, ...}) = 0
lstat("/home/sachin/new-CDM/dummy.c", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=8, ...}) = 0
readlink("/home/sachin/new-CDM/dummy.c", "target.c", 4095) = 8
lstat("/home/sachin/new-CDM/target.c", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
```

So this change is likely an optimization which has a side-effect on a value only in cases where you are supposed to ignore it.

---

Incidentally, your printing of `buf` here was pointless as it would obviously still be NULL.  If this surprises you, it would be worth thinking about why.